# How to import enums without doubling it's values on assignment?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I've noticed a strange enum behavior in Typescript, which depends on if they're defined in the same file or not. Imported enums seem to "double" their values when being assigned:

First, the expected behaviour:

```
enum AllOptions {
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
    C = "c"
}

enum MoreOptions {
    E = "e"
}

enum LimitedOptions {
    A = AllOptions.A,
    C = AllOptions.C,
    E = MoreOptions.E
}

console.log( AllOptions ); // result: Object { A: "a", B: "b", C: "c" }
console.log( MoreOptions ); // result: Object { E: "e" }
console.log( LimitedOptions ); // result: Object { A: "a", C: "c", E: "e" }
```

Now, things look very different, if any of the above definition is imported. Lets move "MoreOptions" into a separate file:

```
// moreoptions.ts
export enum MoreOptions {
    E = "e"
}

console.log( MoreOptions ); // result: Object { E: "e" } -- still looks normal
```

--

```
import { MoreOptions } "./moreoptions";

enum AllOptions {
    A = "a",
    B = "b",
    C = "c"
}


enum LimitedOptions {
    A = AllOptions.A,
    C = AllOptions.C,
    E = MoreOptions.E
}

console.log( AllOptions ); // result: Object { A: "a", B: "b", C: "c" }
console.log( MoreOptions ); // result: Object { E: "e" } -- Looks normal, even here!
console.log( LimitedOptions ); // result: Object { A: "a", C: "c", E: "e", e: "E" } -- What?
```

As you can see, `LimitedOptions` now has 4 enum values: `E: "e"`, and `e: "E"`. This only seems to happen, when I import the enum. This is very unexpected and leads to some problems down the line (like when using `Object.values()` or `Object.keys()`.

I'm using React with Vite, ES2020. It's a freshly setup project.

I prepared a sandbox that displays the same weird behavior:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/nostalgic-cloud-g26src?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Is this a bug, "intended behavior" or am I missing something?